# yup form validation with conditions react js

Tags: reactjs, validation, yup

I need to validate my field according to radio button value. This is the my sample code for the issue
my radio button values are
1st radio button -> values.type === "PO"
2nd radio button -> values.type === "PRE"

this is my validation class,

```
    import * as Yup from "yup";

const POValidation = Yup.object().shape({
  purchaseOrderNumber: Yup.object()
    .required("This field is Required"),
  amount: Yup.number()
    .required("This field is Required")
    .typeError("Amount is required"),
  number: Yup.string()
    .required("This field is Required"),
  term: Yup.object()
    .required("This field is Required")

});
export { POValidation };
```

When user select 1st radio button, values.type === "PO", amount field must be mandatory,
When user select 2st radio button values.type === "PRE", term field must be mandatory. How I apply this conditions to my validation class? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question you want to add validation on the basis of "type".

Here is the code example you can try:

```
import * as Yup from "yup";
const POValidation = Yup.object().shape({

type: Yup.string()
      .required("Please select type.")
      .default("default type"),

amount: Yup.number()
      .when("type", {
        is: (isData) => {
          return (
            isData === "PO"
          );
        },
        then: (thendata) => {
          return (
            Yup.number()
              .required("Please select amount.")
              .test({
                message: "Too Short!",
                test: (value) => {
                  return value >= 1;
                },
              })
              .default("default amount")
              .nullable()
          );
        },
      })
      .nullable(),
term: Yup.number()
      .when("type", {
        is: (isData) => {
          return (
            isData === "PRE"
          );
        },
        then: (thendata) => {
          return (
            Yup.number()
              .required("Please select term.")
              .test({
                message: "Too Short!",
                test: (value) => {
                  return value >= 1;
                },
              })
              .default("default term")
              .nullable()
          );
        },
      })
      .nullable()
});
export { POValidation };
```

Answer (score 1):

You need add a value to store `RadioButton`, I call it is `radioValue`. The you need up date `POValidation` like this:

```
...
  amount: Yup.number().when("radioValue", {
    is: (value) => value=== "PO",
    then: Yup.number()
      .required("This field is Required")
      .typeError("Amount is required"),
  }),
  term: Yup.object().when("radioValue", {
    is: (value) => value=== "PRE",
    then: Yup.object().required("This field is Required"),
  }),
...
```